# Display table data inside detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using ireport designer 5.6.0. I'm trying to display data using table and in page header display number of pages. I found videos on youtube with examples where they put table inside Detail band and generate report,but it's not working for me, it's like in some loop only displaying "Generating report".

When I try to move table in some other band (page footer/header or summary), table is displayer, but page number is only displayed once instead for every page of report.
Is it posible in this version put table in detail band? Or should I maybe create subreport with table in it and put that inside detail band, so that page number would be displayed correctly?

Comment: Do you use Table component in your Report? You can put selected fields directly in Detail band without this component.

Answer (score 1):

Basically detail band will be displayed only when the main dataset query returns rows greater than one. I came to know from your question that there is no query for the main dataset. Also if the main dataset query returns 5 rows, then your table will be displayed or repeated 5 times. Make sure your main dataset query returns only row.

Also have a look at the [problem due to the table component in detail band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815780/ireport-getting-multiple-copies-of-table-in-detail-band)