# Jaspersoft Studio: Report with charts repeats many times

Tags: jasper-reports

I have generated a report with JasperSoft Studio. 
Template is quite large and has 2 pages. (detail: band1 & band2)
It works wonderfully without chart.
Chart should be placed in the middle of the first page (and to the right).

Problem: page repeats with the chart. I have the report contains 6 pages!

Can anyone help me please? Thanks a lot!

Code looks like this:

```
...
<parameter name="par1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="par2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="parN" class="java.lang.String"/>

<parameter name="cdKey" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="cdLabel" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="cdValue" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="cdKey" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="cdLabel" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="cdValue" class="java.lang.Double"/>

<pageHeader>
    <band height="60" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>

<detail>
    <band height="445" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <pie3DChart>
            <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="620" y="50" width="150" height="58" uuid="cab3dff1-8036-4b61-a455-64b63b0ff25a"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <pieDataset>
                <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{cdKey}]]></keyExpression>
                <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cdValue}]]></valueExpression>
                <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{cdLabel}]]></labelExpression>
            </pieDataset>
            <pie3DPlot>
                <plot/>
                <itemLabel/>
            </pie3DPlot>
        </pie3DChart>
    </band>
    <band height="445" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    </band>
</detail>

<pageFooter>
    <band height="40" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter> 


// Java code:
// chartData.add(new ChartData("notebook", "Notebook", 95.0));
// chartData.add(new ChartData("keyboard", "Keyboard", 4.0));
// chartData.add(new ChartData("mouse", "mouse", 1.0));
```

Comment: You placed chart at Detail band. The content of this band is drawing N times, where N is a size of main report's dataset.

Comment: I know that moving the chart into the Summary section resolves the repetition problem.
But Summary is at the bottom. I must place chart in the center-right of the page.

Comment: Have you considered placing the chart in the Background band and check the page number to suppress using `printWhenExpression` (e.g., only print when page number = 1)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iReport: Getting multiple copies of table in detail band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815780/ireport-getting-multiple-copies-of-table-in-detail-band)

Comment: Does not work with background. Page repeats. I have the report contains 6 pages! (But only 1 time chart with $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 0)